# WSGI apache Unsupported Media Type error in custom http request

Tags: django, wsgi

I am using Django to receive request from an AVR.
I uses an custom http POST request containing some byte.

I receive data and store successfully to my database when I use manage.py runserver.

But when I WSGI in apache (WSGIDaemonProcess) I get this error:

[wsgi:error] [pid 5080] [remote 222.157.163.133:4773] Unsupported Media Type: /api/micro/data

How can I fix it?